# get updated data from CursorLoader without an Adapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a sqlite, contentprovider setup for my data. Now i know that all of this works just fine because i have an activity that implements a LoaderCallback interface und has a ListView that is updated via an adapter if the data changes.

In addition i have an activity with the same setup except the ListView. 
In this activity i want to collect the data provided by my contentprovider via CursorLoader in an ArrayList, to fill and update two different views that aren't adapterViews.

I get the Data as follows:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
    String[] projection = new String[]{VitalSet.COL_TYPE};

    return new CursorLoader(
            this,
            CicelyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_DISTINCT,
            projection,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        cursorText.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VitalSet.COL_TYPE)));
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) { }
```

and in my onCreate method i initialise the Loader:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_overview);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

this works fine if i start the activity but the textView does not get updated if i add new data. Is there some listenerMethod i need to implement if i dont use an adapter or is it just not possible to get updated data without adapters?

i have the neccessary notifications in my contentprovider query and insertmethods.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: ContentResolver.registerContentObserver or similsr thing

Comment: Yes, thanks. That works quite well, but my approach above works also, my mistake was that i had different URIs for query and insert. thats why the updates werent recognized.

Comment: oops,  sorry,  I forgot that CursorLoader registers a ContentObserver on its Cursor,  see CursorLoader.loadInBackground method